# How do I implement this as a recursive function?

Tags: scala, recursion

How can I define this function recursively?

Somehow k has to stay the same, but as we can't use a j, we have to change k for the next recursion step

[image: http://i.imgur.com/BnQlE1F.png]

Comment: Why not provide the actual code instead of an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual for recursive functions you have to pass `n`, `k` and `j` as well with every call. This is very logical especially if you think about one particular function execution. It only calculates one step of the incremental product. As a consequence the function signature looks as follows:

```
the_func(n, k, j):
    ...
```

You have to increment the j after every particular calculation to pass the next `j` to the following execution. Furthermore you have to add a termination condition which looks like the following:

```
if(k==j):
    ... Pop back the whole recursion...
```

Comment: I also don't see how to do it without passing the j. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Yes, because it is not possible without the `j`

Answer (score 1):

If you have to do this as a recursive function, try something like:

```
def f(n: Double, k: Double) = {
  def f0(k1:Double): Double =
    if (k1 >= 1.0f)
      (n-k+k1)/k1 * f0(k1-1)
    else
      1.0f
  f0(k)
}
```

It is worth checking searching for foldLeft and foldRight and reading about the differences.

Comment: You don't the need third third variable if you count backwards as you know k  has a lower bound of 1 and then you multiple everything by 1. Worth looking up tail recursion.

Comment: hm. ok. as we have (n-k+j)/j , how do we count down with k without saving the initial value of k that has to be used in every step?

Comment: @user6454491 .. I'm counting down with the k1 value. The recursive function is f0, I start by calling f0 with k1=k, values n and k are constant. Each recursive call to f0 is decrementing k1, i.e. .. * f0(k1-1). The end condition is when k1 = 0 in that case I multiply by 1, to give the answer. If you rename k1 to j, it may make more sense.

Comment: I see. thanks. I will keep in mind that I can to it like this as well. 
You mentioned tail recursion and I tried implementing the tail recursion with 4 parameters like this

    `@annotation.tailrec

    def fnk2(n:Double, k:Double, j:Double, t: Double=1): Double={

     if(j==k) (n-k+j)/j

     else fnk2(n,k,j+1, (n-k+j)/j*(n-k+j)/j)

    }`

the result is not correct though and I can't find the mistake

Comment: In your function, your else is a call to fnk2 and eventually you will just return the expression (n-k+j)/j when j==k. If you look at mine, you see that you have to multiply by the next value, with the last value being 1. i.e. effectively creating an expression like ... x1 * ( x2 * ( ..... ( * 1.0 ....  this maybe makes more sense if you look read about foldLeft.